# Removing caret sign and adding parentheses to pager numbers

Tags: text-processing

I have strings like these

```
NE234GJKLKU,*9^789098
NE345HJsdfe,*1^534656
YBKJNJKHBKK,*1^987654
UTGHNKOIUYO,*1^123421
ERTYUIJHGLK,*1^456666
```

that I wish to be:

```
NE234GJKLKU,*(978)-9098
NE345HJsdfe,*(153)-4656
YBKJNJKHBKK,*(198)-7654
UTGHNKOIUYO,*(112)-3421
ERTYUIJHGLK,*(145)-6666
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

try `sed`

```
sed -r -e 's/\^//g;s/^.{13}/&(/;s/^.{17}/&)-/' file

NE234GJKLKU,*(978)-9098
NE345HJsdfe,*(153)-4656
YBKJNJKHBKK,*(198)-7654
UTGHNKOIUYO,*(112)-3421
ERTYUIJHGLK,*(145)-6666
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do:

```
sed -E 's/(.)\^(..)/(\1\2)-/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `sed` solution:

```
$ sed 's,*,*(,g' FILE | sed -E 's,([0-9])\^([b0-9])([0-9]),\1\2\3)-,g'
NE234GJKLKU,*(978)-9098
NE345HJsdfe,*(153)-4656
YBKJNJKHBKK,*(198)-7654
UTGHNKOIUYO,*(112)-3421
ERTYUIJHGLK,*(145)-6666
```

Single line:

```
$ sed -E 's,\*,*(,g;s,([0-9])\^([b0-9])([0-9]),\1\2\3)-,g' FILE
NE234GJKLKU,*(978)-9098
NE345HJsdfe,*(153)-4656
YBKJNJKHBKK,*(198)-7654
UTGHNKOIUYO,*(112)-3421
ERTYUIJHGLK,*(145)-6666
```